# SQL Query Dependent Logic in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `TableX`. It contains three columns: `A` `INT` , `B` `INT` and `C` `VARCHAR(1)` (valid values for column C being the name of the columns 'A' or 'B'). I need to count the number of occurrences where either of the following conditions are met:

1. When `C` is `NULL` and *does* contains values in either `A` or `B` greater than zero. or
2. When `C` is `NOT NULL` (i.e. 'A' or 'B') and the value in the specified column (`A` or `B`) is either zero or `NULL`.

My current stored procedure looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ispcSomeName @NumOcc INT OUTPUT 
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [NumOcc] 
FROM TableName 
WHERE (C IS NULL 
       AND ((A IS NOT NULL OR A > 0) OR 
            (B IS NOT NULL OR B > 0))) 
    OR (CritCarType IS NOT NULL 
        AND (CASE SET @TmpColumnName = CritCareType 
                 WHEN N'A' THEN (A IS NULL OR A <= 0) 
                 WHEN N'B' THEN (B IS NULL OR B <= 0)))
GO
```

The problem is that I need to check the column that `C` references. That is if `C = 'A'`, I need to check if `A IS NOT NULL OR A <= 0`. There is clearly an issue with the `SET` in the final `WHERE`. I have got a few of these types of SPs to author and I want to avoid complex TSQL if I can help it...

**How do I dynamically get reference to the relevant column in the `WHERE` clause?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Count(*)
from tab
where 
(
    C is null and (Coalesce(A,0)>0 or Coalesce(B,0)>0)
)
or 
(
    C is not null and Case when C='A' then Coalesce(A,0) 
    when C='B' then Coalesce(B,0) end <=0
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. This looks great. I will test this shortly. Thanks again...

Comment: I am confused over the relevence of the zero in the `COALESCE(A, 0)`, is this just ensuring that A is always chosen in the undelying `CASE` statement?

Comment: it's the value choosen in case of A is Null
e.g. condition "does contains values in either A or B greater than zero" so will not meet if A<=0  also if  A is NULL it will not meet because then 0 will be taken for comparison